# How do I create a Fully qualified Assembly for a sandbox solution?

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I followed the steps as below to create fully qualified assembly.

1. Open Visual Studio
2. Go to Tools –> External Tools –> Add

   > **Title**: Get Qualified Assembly Name
   >   **Command**: Powershell.exe
   >   **Arguments**: -command "[System.Reflection.AssemblyName]::GetAssemblyName(\"$(TargetPath)\").FullName"
3. Check "Use Output Window".

But it does not creating the assembly for sandbox solution

Comment: Can you give more details? It is difficult to understand what your situation is.

Comment: its sandbox solution which we are using in share-point to create a web parts or as per our requirement